# Gunicorn - Python returns inexplicable result intermittently

Tags: python, logging, gunicorn

I have a pretty rudimentary web server using Gunicorn. The callback is a native python function. The following is a snippet of the app function in the callback. After the gunicorn parent process is re-started, sometimes the raise_error function is called with VOCFE_STATUS_NO_SCHEMA, without the log line above it being printed. This happens for requests that have been working before the restart, and happens to all 8 child gunicorn processes that are spawned. Killing an individual gunicorn child process corrects the issue in the killed child - and the request processing is fine.

If the issue doesn't manifest for the first request after the restart, it never happens.

Co-workers are as out of theories as I am, so any valid theory would help me.

```
if path not in SCHEMA_IGNORANT_PATHS:

         if 'serverState' in body and 'schemaName' in body['serverState']:
             schema = body['serverState']['schemaName']
         elif len (path_bits) > 1:
             schema = path_bits[1]
         else:
             schemas = be_db.select('public.tenant', {}, ['schema_name'])
             if not schemas or len(schemas) == 0:
                 LOG.info("No schema in the tenant table")
                 return raise_error (response_callback, VOCFE_STATUS_NO_SCHEMA)
             if len(schemas) > 1:
                 LOG.info("No client signaled schema, but {} schemas available".format(len(schemas)))
                 return raise_error (response_callback, VOCFE_STATUS_INVALID_SCHEMA)

             schema = schemas[0]['schema_name']
```

Comment: Are you sure your `LOG` setup is working?

Comment: Yes. the current setup has 8 children spawned - and all of them show the same symptoms. Killing any of the children makes the issue go away for the  restarted child.

Comment: Show where and how You define loggers